# Can my OAuth2 client retrieve the canonical user ID from the access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

Using the OAUth2 web server flow, I've:

1. User tries to access www.third-party.com/welcome
2. User is redirected to www.myserver.com/oauth2/authorize
3. MyServer authenticates user, and redirects them to www.third-party.com/welcome?code=...
4. third-party.com talks to myserver.com behind the scenes, exchanges `code` for an OAuth2 access and refresh token.

All good. Now third-party.com needs to determine the users' canonical username, so it can make ReSTFUL URI calls to resources like www.myserver.com/api/{username}/details

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth on ASP.NET MVC. My OAuth2 controller looks like this:

namespace OurOAuth2.Server.Controllers {
    [Authorize]
    public class OAuth2Controller : Controller {
        private readonly AuthorizationServer authServer;
        private readonly IOAuth2ClientAuthorizationStore authStore;

```
    private OAuth2AuthorizationServerHost authHost {
        get {
            return (((OAuth2AuthorizationServerHost)authServer.AuthorizationServerServices));
        }
    }

    public OAuth2Controller(AuthorizationServer authServer, IOAuth2ClientAuthorizationStore authStore) {
        this.authServer = authServer;
        this.authStore = authStore;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Token() {
        var result = this.authServer.HandleTokenRequest(this.Request);
        return (result.AsActionResult());
    }

    public ActionResult Secure() {
        return (Content("This is secure!"));
    }

    public ActionResult Authorize() {
        var request = this.authServer.ReadAuthorizationRequest(this.Request);
        if (authHost.CanBeAutoApproved(request)) {
            var approval = this.authServer.PrepareApproveAuthorizationRequest(request, HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            authStore.StoreAuthorization(request.ClientIdentifier, User.Identity.Name, request.Scope);

            // Any way, at THIS point, to include the canonical username in the 
            // token exchange?
            var response = this.authServer.Channel.PrepareResponse(approval);
            return response.AsActionResult();
        }
        // no scope authorization workflow yet.
        return (null);
    }
}
```

I can see three approaches:

1. A (non-ReSTful) URI endpoint on www.myserver.com that will return user details for whomever authorized the supplier bearer token - so the third-party app just hits /userinfo with the OAuth2 bearer token and gets back the user's details, including the username.
2. Retrieving the user identity from the access token - but my understanding is that this requires the decrypt key, which should **not** be part of the client application (?)
3. Including some additional user state data in the token exchange between the third-party app and the oauth2 authorization server.

I'm guessing (2) is a bad idea. (1) is easy enough to implement, but I'd love to know whether approach (3) is possible and how I would go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Most common pattern is to exchange access token for user details same as Facebook does:

"Token" endpoint provides the access token

"Me" endpoint provides user details(according to granted scopes) related to the access token(bearer token) carried by the request as Authorization header.

Comment: https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/563904mainqimgf07893a9156900734ce3310a938e86d5.png
Hi; I look for u response and I think that you talk about this schema, but one thing that escapes me is how facebook perform the get /Me call using only the access token? do you have any idea?